# How to rename bunch of files with AWK?

Tags: ubuntu, awk

I am new to Ubuntu, i have a small problem: i have a lot of files which i want to rename according to each line of text in another file **names.txt**. And how to do that with AWK?

Files which i want to rename

```
file1.html
file2.html
file3.html
file4.html
```

Structure of file **names.txt**

```
Moscow
Kosice
Warsaw 
Budapest
```

Final result

```
Moscow.html
Kosice.html
Warsaw.html
Budapest.html
```

File **names.txt** is at the same folder with all other files that i want to rename.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: awk is a tool for manipulating text. The shell is a tool for manipulating (creating/destroying/moving) files and processes and has a language designed to do just that plus sequence calls to other tools. So, renaming files is not a job for awk, it's a job for your shell.

Answer (score -2):

awk can help you get the shell commands you need, but doing it with just awk is not the way to do it:

```
awk 'BEGIN{x=1} {printf "%s.html file%d.html\n", $0, x; x++}' names.txt | xargs -l mv
```

Here awk will process the names.txt file and for each line it creates %s.html file%d.html. In which %s is the text found on that line in the file and %d is an incremented number.

Next this is passed to xargs which will call for every line (that is what -l does) will call mv and pass the text on that line as arguments.

NB. This will break if you want to rename for files with spaces. In that case you need to alter this line a bit.